# Why does bash keep showing my ruby version in the prompt?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, terminal

I was using ruby for the first time yesterday and I installed some packages / gems without much awareness and now bash keeps showing my ruby version 2.4 everywhere I go. How do I remove it?

[image: iterm]

Comment: What's the value of `echo "$PS1"`?

Comment: ```echo "$PS1"``` is ```%{$fg_bold[green]%}${PWD/#$HOME/~}%{$reset_color%}$(git_prompt_info) ⌚ %{$fg_bold[red]%}%*%{$reset_color%}```

Answer (score 2):

There's a few places where `$PS1` is set, most likely are `.profile`, `.bashrc`, or `.bashrc_profile`.

You can have a look at the ps1 functions provided by rvm (assuming that's what you are using). There's some useful stuff in there.

```
less "`echo $rvm_path`/contrib/ps1_functions"
```

If you want to know what gems you have installed: `gem list` will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

I faced with the similar issue after install `bash_it` and I was able to fix it by edit the `rvm.sh` file

Before
[image: before]

`vim /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh`

```
if
  [ -n "${BASH_VERSION:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] &&
  test "`\command \ps -p $$ -o ucomm=`" != dash &&
 #test "`\command \ps -p $$ -o ucomm=`" != sh
  test "`\command \ps -p $$ -o ucomm=`" != bash
then
```

After
[image: after]